# TRAZER DOIS DADOS EM COLUNAS E NÃO EM LINHAS

Tags: mysql, sql

me ajudem na seguinte questão:

Tenho alguns CPF's e cada um deles retorna dois contratos bem como a data de criação desse contrato, como mostra o exemplo abaixo:

| CPF | NUMERO CONTRATO | DATA ENTRADA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XXXXXXXXXX | 12345678910 | 2021-12-10 |
| XXXXXXXXXX | 10987654321 | 2022-05-15 |

Gostaria que todas as informãções viessem em uma única linha, como por exemplo:

| CPF | NUMERO CONTRATO 1 | DATA ENTRADA 1 | NUMERO CONTRATO 2 | DATA ENTRADA 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXXXXXXXXX | 12345678910 | 2021-12-10 | 10987654321 | 2022-05-15 |

Como posso fazer isso diretamente na query?

Obrigada!

Comment: A quantidade de contratos por CPF será sempre 2, ou isso poderá variar?

Comment: edita a pergunta e bota a query atual (Y)

Comment: Sempre será 2 a quantidade de CPF's

Answer (score -1):

Lilian,

Uma solução para funcionar com um número independente de contratos é usar o [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat) e trazer a lista para cada grupo.

Dado a situação hipotética abaixo:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela (
    id INT(11),
    data_entrada DATE,
    cpf CHAR(14),
    num_contrato CHAR(11)

);

insert into tabela (id, data_entrada, cpf, num_contrato) values 
(1,  '2020-04-01', '111.111.111-11', '12345678910'),
(2,  '2020-01-01', '111.111.111-11', '12345673211'),
(3,  '2020-02-01', '111.111.111-11', '12345678112'),
(4,  '2020-08-01', '222.222.222-22', '12345673211'),
(5,  '2020-02-10', '222.222.222-22', '12345678113'),
(6,  '2020-06-03', '333.333.333-33', '32345674517'),
(7,  '2020-05-01', '444.444.444-44', '12345673211'),
(8,  '2020-05-01', '444.444.444-44', '12345673581'),
(9,  '2020-05-01', '444.444.444-44', '12345678910'),
(10, '2020-05-01', '555.555.555-55', '12345678562'),
(11, '2020-05-02', '666.666.666-66', '12345679990'),
(12, '2020-05-03', '666.666.666-66', '12345679991'),
(13, '2020-05-02', '666.666.666-66', '12345679992')
;
```

Utilizando a query:

```
select 
    cpf,
    group_concat(num_contrato) as contratos,
    group_concat(data_entrada) as datas
from tabela
group by cpf
```

Obtém-se o seguinte resultado:

```
|cpf            |contratos                             |datas|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

111.111.111-11  12345678910,12345673211,12345678112    2020-04-01,2020-01-01,2020-02-01
222.222.222-22  12345673211,12345678113                2020-08-01,2020-02-10
333.333.333-33  32345674517                            2020-06-03
444.444.444-44  12345678910,12345673581,12345673211    2020-05-01,2020-05-01,2020-05-01
555.555.555-55  12345678562                            2020-05-01
666.666.666-66  12345679990,12345679991,12345679992    2020-05-02,2020-05-03,2020-05-02
```

Então, na sua aplicação, você pode converter os contratos e datas em arrays, sendo que cada contrato terá a sua repectiva data com o mesmo índice.

Segue o fiddle da solução: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/85f537/5

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Ótima resposta, dando upvote para tirar do negativo ao menos... :)

Comment: Obrigado! Até hoje não entendi o motivo dos negativos.

Comment: A comunidade BR é muito fraca, foi um dos motivos pra eu desanimar com a contribuição aqui...